# "ValueError: Invalid format specifier" when formatting a calculated variable

Tags: python

Only my third or so time working with python and since Im following along with a Gaddis textbook, I have to make an ingredient adjuster program for baking cookies. However, the last lines of code where I try and format the numbers, ValueError: Invalid format specifier comes up when I try to run it.

Read some of the questions similar to mine on here, however I found the instances of those programs were much more complicated to understand and relate back to mine.

```
#The recipe produces 48 cookies with this amount of the ingredients.
#Write a program that asks the user how many cookies he or she wants to make,
#then displays the number of cups of each ingredient needed for the specified
#number of cookies.

#1.5 cups of sugar
#1 cup of butter
#2.75 cups of flour

default_batch = 48
defaultCups_Sugar = 1.5
defaultCups_Butter = 1
defaultCups_Flour = 2.75

num_cookies = float(input("How many cookies would you like to make? "))

calCups_Sugar = (num_cookies/default_batch)*defaultCups_Sugar
calCups_Butter = (num_cookies/default_batch)*defaultCups_Butter
calCups_Flour = (num_cookies/default_batch)*defaultCups_Flour

print ("It would take the following amount of ingredients to       make", \
   num_cookies, "cookies:")

print ("Cups of Sugar:", format(calCups_Sugar, ";.2f"))
print ("Cups of Butter:", format(calCups_Butter, ";.2f"))
print ("Cups of Flour:", format(calCups_Flour, ";.2f"))
```

I expect the output to only go as far as two decimal places however the ValueError: Invalid format specifier error message appears instead when I run it.

Comment: If you search in your browser for "Python format specification", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.

Answer (score 2):

Format specifiers in Python do not contain a semicolon. The correct syntax for formatting a string to two decimal places is `format(number, ".2f")`, not `format(number, ";.2f")`

Comment: Thanks for the help!